# Instaling Linux on a machine with Asrock Z87 Extreme 6

Tags: linux, uefi

I am not able to install Linux in my newly built machine.
I think it can be related with my MB (Asrock Z87 Extreme6). 
I already have Windows 8.1 installed without UEFI.

When I boot (linux) from the BluRay Drive, if I use legacy boot it won't boot at all. If I choose to use UEFI, sometimes it boots, but it fails to install.

I have tried several distros (Ubuntu, Debian, Slackware), but with no success. Any idea what's the problem?

I have even tried OpenBSD, but no luck there as well.

Machine configuration:

- Kingston HyperX blu Memory 16GB
- Seagate 1TB SATA600
- Asrock Z87 Extreme6
- Intel Core i5 4570, 3.2GHz
- Asus BW 16D1HT
- *Using onboard GPU*

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you would post any details like error messages that you see or if you describe what's happening when it fails.

Comment: What Mauro said. Also, are you 100% sure it is not a UEFI setup? Can you boot a live session CD? I see no reason why your MB would cause problems.

Comment: Sorry, at work now. Not able to post the concrete errors. Will do it later. Windows 8.1 is not in UEFI 100%. Was not able to boot from a live CD.

Comment: When I try to boot without UEFI I get "Machine check error" in big letters. Updated the UEFI, booted with UEFI, I was able to load the installation menu until the partitions menu, I don't have the time now to go forward with this. I have to take a new try later. I will keep you updated.

Comment: I would need to reinstall windows, because is not UEFI. 
Does anyone knows why I get the "Machine check error" when using a non UEFI boot?

Comment: I just did a PXE install of Debian Wheezy on this motherboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short: ***don't use DVI-D, use HDMI***  `>:(`

Well guys, gave it a try again. And finally did it! :D

Just installed Linux Mint debian based version. 
This time the only problem I found was the display, when I had it connected to my onboard card using the DVI-D nothing was shown, had to connect it using a HDMI cable. :( 
I would really like to have it connected in the DVI-D port, need to HDMI to connect other devices.

I was getting tired of running Debian in a virtual machine. But this cable thing is really a big downside. :( Well, when I get more time I'll try to fix it.

I am also starting to wonder if previously the live distros were starting but I didn't noticed because I got no picture. Today I found that the system has booted because I've been working on Windows and left the speakers ON, so I heard the starting sound of the Linux Mint... maybe it was always working... :(